# An English word that means "Unable to go to work due to injuries or sickness"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Contrary to what I would expect, there's pretty much no article with this words other than online automated dictionaries (which I don't find truthworthy). So far I have found **Laboral Inhability** but, as I said, I can't find a text with the usage of that phrase, which leads me to believe said phrase is most likely incorrect. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
An example in a sentence would be, in the context of a worker who is unable to go to work for X days due to an injured knee:

"By doing this new therapy method, we can reduce the time of **laboral inhability** because the worker would recover twice as fast as with the old one."

Comment: In the US it would be something like "sick leave".

Comment: @Rathony Thanks, I have updated my question with a example in a sentence.

Comment: In terms of the total sick-leave time for a workforce, as seen by the employer, "lost time" is the usual term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HotLicks commented, [sick leave](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sick-leave) is broadly used to mean:

> a period of time during which you do not work because you are ill

[Macmillan Online Dictionary]

More formal (official) term for this period would be *medical leave (of absence)*.

Comment: Medical Leave is the one that fits best. I'll take it.

Answer (score 1):

[**Lost Work Time**](https://www.google.com/search?q=lost-worktime&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=lost-work%20time) –Google search:

*On the job illness and injury resulting in **lost work time** among a national cohort of emergency medical services professionals.* –[ncbi.nlm.nih.gov](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17918231)

***LOST-WORKTIME*** INJURIES AND ILLNESSES: CHARACTERISTICS AND RESULTING DAYS AWAY FROM WORK, 2002 –[bls.gov](http://www.bls.gov/news.release/archives/osh2_03252004.pdf)

---

**Lost Time**

> FORMULAS for CALCULATING RATES
>   OSHA Recordable Incident Rate
>   Lost Time Case Rate
>   Lost Work Day Rate (LWD)
>   DART Rate (Days Away/Restricted or Job Transfer Rate)
>   Severity Rate
>
> ...
>
> **Lost Time Case Rate (LTC)**
>   The Lost Time Case Rate is a similar calculation, only it uses the number of cases that contained lost work days. The calculation is made by multiplying the number of incidents that were lost time cases by 200,000 and then dividing that by the employee labor hours at the company.
>
> LTC Rate = Number of Lost Time Cases x 200,000 / Number of Employee Labor Hours Worked
>
> –[nmmcc.com, PDF](http://[%E2%80%93nmmcc.com,%20PDF])

---

> "By doing this new therapy method, we can reduce the *lost (work) time* of the worker, because they would recover twice as fast as with the old one."

Answer (score 1):

"**Incapacitation**," or "**incapacity**" would also work for use outside the more formal constructs of employer-employee relations.

Comment: Convalescence also fits to a point.